# How to create a UIView outside UIViewController?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I want to create a UIView in classB calling from classA to show on MainView(my UIViewController).

[image: illustration]

can anyone help me to fix my code?

classA:

```
+ (void)trigger
{
    [classB viewOn:[MainView new]];
}
```

classB:

```
+ (void)viewOn:(id)sender
{
    MainView *pointer = (MainView *)sender;

    classB *view = [[classB alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(380, 200, 100, 50)];
    view.backgroundColor = [[UIColor greenColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.5f];
    view.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

    UILabel *lab = [UILabel new];
    lab.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 50);
    lab.text = @"test";

    [view addSubview:lab];
    [pointer.view addSubview:view];
}
```

When I use MainView class to call classB by [classB viewOn:self] it works fine. But if I want to trigger it from classA, how can I do?

Answer (score 1):

> When I use MainView class to call classB by [classB viewOn:self] it
>   works fine.

That's because you're casting `sender` to a `MainView *`.

> But if I want to trigger it from classA, how can I do?

If you want to do the same thing from ClassA, you'll need a pointer to an instance of MainView to pass in. I see that you're trying to do that already...

> `[classB viewOn:[MainView new]];`

That's probably not the right way to initialize your MainView, though... views are generally initialized with `alloc` followed by `initWithFrame:`.

Before you spend too much time trying to make this all work, you should think about the different roles your objects are playing here. Normally, you'd use a view controller to manage the creation and configuration of your view hierarchy. One way that a view controller would be useful here is to keep a reference to your instance of MainView. Your view controller could then instantiate ClassB and add that new view to MainView. You seem to be trying to make your ClassA work as a view controller as well as a view -- that's probably just going to muddy the waters and make it more difficult for you to learn to work effectively in Objective-C and Cocoa Touch.

Comment: It seems that I overestimate myself to handle the codes here. You are right, I really should rethink my logic for putting classes and their  roles. But if I try to fix them, how can I do?

Comment: Start by figuring out what you want to happen. Forget about objects and classes; what do you want the user to see? Read up on MVC in Apple's iOS documentation so that you understand how the MVC pattern is used (and it's use a LOT) in iOS -- that will help you organize your program in a way that'll work well with iOS. I can't be more specific than that because I really can't tell what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: It's true that my coding experience from a poor language knowledge stage..
I try implement the idea start by Objective-C. To continue the project, I need to do more reading. Thanks for your time and help, I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Use delegation.
It is quite simple.
All you have to do is go to `ClassA`.
Make it look like this

```
@interface ClassA: NSObject <ClassB>
```

and now you can call it from `ClassA`.

Hope I helped as I am kind of new to objective-c.